# Python's MySQLdb changes double quotes to single quotes

Tags: python, mysql, escaping, quotes, executemany

I'm using python to read values from REST API and write to a MySQL table. One of the returned values is a JSON, which I want to store in the DB.

The value returned by the API has escaped quotes and looks something like:

```
{\"dashboard\":\"val\"}
```

When I use print, I see that the escape characters are replaced with the actual quotes (which is the desired outcome):

```
{"dashboard":"val"}
```

However, when I'm using the MySQLdb execute or executemany (with tokenised params) - the value written to the database has all the double quotes replaced with single quotes, making it a non-valid json:

```
{'dashboard':'val'}
```

How do I avoid that?

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your library into `mysql.connector` or `pymysql` or etc , because `MySQLdb` has some problems you can not predict. Even though your parameters and base_sql are correct. I recommend `mysql.connector`, because it is MySQL official library. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/